# How do I print two loops in a certain format?

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, xpath

I'm still learning python and I'm really new to it

I'd like to have a table that looks something like this using selenium.
I'd like to print a list of text on the left and a class id on the right handside.
Would you recommend me any changes I should do?
I'm using driver.find_elements_by_xpath to get both values/classID

```
Size         Availability

M            In Stock
L            In Stock
XL           Out of Stock
XXL          In Stock
```

My codes are:

```
for value,ii in zip(item_checker, size_availability):
        print(value.text, ii.get_attribute('class'),)
```

Thank you so much for helping me if you do!

Comment: Pandas is a good way to store data or you could just format it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) library to format output to look like fancy tables.

First example:

```
from tabulate import tabulate

table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],["Earth",6371,5973.6],
          ["Moon",1737,73.5],["Mars",3390,641.85]]

print(tabulate(table))
```

Output:

```
-----  ------  -------------
Sun    696000     1.9891e+09
Earth    6371  5973.6
Moon     1737    73.5
Mars     3390   641.85
-----  ------  -------------
```

Second example:

```
print(tabulate(table, headers=["Planet","R (km)", "mass (x 10^29 kg)"]))
```

Output:

```
Planet      R (km)    mass (x 10^29 kg)
--------  --------  -------------------
Sun         696000           1.9891e+09
Earth         6371        5973.6
Moon          1737          73.5
Mars          3390         641.85
```